How To Get Cell Fracture To Fill Faces
I've been doing Blender for about 3 weeks now and am trying to get a not-so-complex object to fracture using the Cell Fracture method. I cannot seem to get it to fill in all of the faces on the interior of the fractures.
I could certainly fill these faces in by hand, if my fracture didn't need to be finer than what I could do by hand. There's no way I could do this for any significant number of objects and then reassemble the object structure.
For more context, I want to explode the object (e.g. with an impact), and don't want thin pieces looking like they are cut from a plane coming apart.
If this is a duplicate, I apologize. I have beaten my head against Google trying to figure this out for a full day now. So any help is appreciated.


I can't replicate this when I create a default primitive object and the default settings for cell fracture using the preset in the add-on.  So, I wonder if there is something trickier happening.  Including your .blend may help with the original object.

I couldn't replicate it either. I started a new project, deleted all faces and edges from the default cube, then re-added all the faces. It worked fine in several re-tries of the Cell Fracture, like you're saying. So I went and rebuilt my object from the ground up (starting with nothing but vertices) and it wouldn't work after like 10 redo's of the Cell Fracture using the same settings as the cube.
This object is proprietary company property so I can't share a .blend with it. If this is just an aberration with my object then I think that's my answer, and I'll keep trying. Thanks!

Maybe something is confusing Cell-Fracture's notion of 'inside' and 'outside'. Is there anything non-manifold about your geometry?

I don't know how to determine if I have non-manifold geometry. I have a basic L shape that's solid with some depth with no internal faces. I've recreated the very basic scenario using Geometry Nodes to see if that will help me, but I am running into the issue of intersecting quadrilaterals not joining properly. Maybe this is  good example of non-manifoldness?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319861/geometry-nodes-fill-quadrilaterals-that-intersect
